# Write out huge XElement as XML string - OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create a large XML file which unfortunately I have no control over.

One of the elements of the XML contains hundreds of thousands of elements (up to 500k), so the resulting XML of the XElement is quite large, however still smaller than what I would expect for an `OutOfMemory` exception.

The below code is being used to serialise objects to XML, then use an XmlReader to stream that XML and pull out the element I need (which is huge). I'm then trying to compress the element (using GZip to Base64) **however**, I can't even get this far because `xmlReader.ReadOuterXml` throws an `OutOfMemory` exception.

I have tried various ways of doing this, including using `XmlDocument` (`.InnerXml`/`.OuterXml`) and `XDocument` with `XElements` (`.ToString()`) but all of them throw `OutOfMemory` exceptions.

The reason I'm trying to convert my element to a string in the first place is because my compression expects a `byte[]` - I'm not sure if my approach is flawed in this case.

Code:

```
private string GetCompressed(object obj)
{
        XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        // Serialise the XML to an XDocument so that we can manipulate it
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Serialise to the memory stream
            serialiser.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);

            // Reset the position to 0.
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Create an XML reader to stream out the results
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream))
            {
                while (xmlReader.Read())
                {
                    if (xmlReader.Name == "ElementIWant")
                    {
                        return CompressXML(xmlReader.ReadOuterXml()); //<= ReadOuterXml() throws OutOfMemory
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: When you call ReadOuterXml then that piece of data is needed in memory twice. One obvious approach to halve that is to replace the MemStream with a TempFile. Also, run this in 64-bit mode (turn of "Prefer 32").

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the temp file part. Unfortunately I'm still getting memory issues. Any other ideas?

Comment: You didn't specify 32/64 yet. But when things get big, use streams. There is a method to create a subtree, you should be able to clone that to a stream (maybe with an XmlWriter). Your CompressXml will have to change to accepting a stream too.